# Params object functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've used the params hash in rails and am currently learning node/express.  I could always get the params hash to work but never really understood exactly what is going on with it. Here is a quote frome express.js documentation on params.

'This property is an array containing properties mapped to the named route "parameters". For example if you have the route /user/:name, then the "name" property is available to you as req.params.name. This object defaults to {}.'

I am not sure what is going on. So

```
req.params.name
```

So on the request we are taking the property 'name' from the object params? but then params is also a route as well so we are getting a property from a route as well?  I understand that the :name will be replaced with the params.name output but how does it actually do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this isn't your confusion, but just to make sure, let's be clear that `req.params` has nothing to do with the request body or querystring (those are stored in `req.body` and `req.query` respectively...assuming you have the proper middleware linked in to parse the request body).

The first parameter passed to `app.VERB` (where `VERB` is usually one of `get`, `post`, but could be any HTTP verb aka method) can be any one of the following:

1. String: the string will be treated as kind of a pseudo-regular expression that will be converted into a real regular expression (more on this later).
2. RegExp: regular expressions are not interpreted in any way.
3. Array: the elements of the array will be converted to strings and joined with `|`, then treated as (1).

If you use a regular string, you have access to a regular-expression-like syntax.  Here are some valid paths you can use and the results:

1. `/foo/:bar`: Will match `/foo/abc`, `/foo/123`, etc.  `req.params.bar` will be `abc` or `123` respectively.
2. `/foo/:bar?`: Will match `/foo` or `/foo/abc`, etc.  `req.params.bar` will be `undefined` or `abc` respectively.
3. `/foo/:bar*`: Will match `/foo`, `/foo/abc`, `/foo/abc/xyz`, etc.  `req.params.bar` will be `undefined`, `abc`, and `abc`.  How do you get `xyz`?  It's in the `req.params` array, but it's not particularly convenient to extract.
4. `/foo/:bar(\d+)`: Will match `/foo/123` but not `/foo/abc`.  In the case of the match, `req.params.bar` will be `123`.

Of course all of these things combined in mind-numbing ways of (IMO) diminishing usefulness.

One thing to note is that characters that are normally meaningful in regular expressions, like the period, are not meaningful in route strings.  For example, the path `/download/:name.:ext` will match `/download/foo.jpg` but not `/download/fooxjpg`.

If you want to understand how all this "magic" happens, you'll have to take a look at the Express source code.  At the very bottom of the heap is the function `pathRegexp`, which takes your path, figures out if it's a string, regex, or array, and converts it to a real regex.  You can find that function here:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/utils.js

Wading through the regex generation takes some dedication, but it's well within the reach of someone who understands regular expressions well.  Then, once you've grokked that function, you can look at at the `Route.prototype.match` method, which can be found here:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js

You'll see that if the route matches, params is populated from the regex generated by `pathRegexp` in `utils.js`.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, something like this:

```
app.get('/quote/:name', function(req, res) {
   req.params.name 
 }
```

But if you want to get the query string parameters then you have to use:
(req.query) Checks query string params, ex: ?name=Alex Checks urlencoded body params

(req.body), ex: name=alex To utilize urlencoded request bodies, req.body should be an object. This can be done by using the _express.bodyParser middleware.